# Fast grouping and aggregation of huge data set

Tags: language-agnostic, grouping, aggregation, large-data

I've got a huge amount of data (stored in file, but it is irrelevant - main part is that the data doesn't fit into memory) - let's say 10<sup>9</sup> lines of records.

The record consists of time, some set of keys, and data. The keys aren't unique.
for example

```
keys:          data:
A | B | C |    
----------------------
1 | 2 | 3 |    10 
1 | 1 | 3 |    150
1 | 1 | 2 |    140
1 | 2 | 5 |    130
5 | 3 | 2 |    120
...
```

I need to go through all of the data, and filter them using user-defined filter (this isn't problem), and then aggregate, count sum, and return rows with highest data.

For example, in given data, I want to sum every data grouping by A and C.

expected result:

```
A | C | data
------------
1 | 3 | 160
1 | 2 | 140
1 | 5 | 130

------------ following (data isn't in 3 highest value) doesn't concern me.
5 | 2 | 120
```

I implemented this using naive solution, I have `Dictionary<tuple(A, C), long>`, and sum there. But the problem is, that there can be more unique combinations of A,C than I can fit into memory.

I cannot pre-sum any of the data, as any filtering may appear, nor use SQL (relational DB doesn't fit well for me).

Are there any memory-efficient algorithms usable for grouping this way? How does SQL handle so much data? I'm able to do the grouping on SQL, but there are some reasons why I do not want to use it.

Or, what should I google? I haven't found any useful article on this issue.

(I'm using C#, the question is rather theoretical than 'use following code:')

Comment: have you considered using mapreduce? it seems perfectly fit! http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/labs.google.com/en//papers/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf

Comment: @amit: no, I've never heard of it. thanks for the link, i'll have a look.

Comment: mapreduce is a framework for cutting data into chunk, first you `map` it into pairs: (key,value) and then given a list of values for each keys, you make your `reduce` step (your summarize). it was originally implemented in c++, but hadoop is a java version, and I assume a C# version is available as well. good luck!

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a database?

Comment: @ypercube > I didn't say that I don't want to use a database - I don't want to use SQL.

Comment: @Yossarian: Sorry, i misinterpreted your *"relational DB doesn't fit well for me"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the comments for the question might be considered as an answer...

You can use [mapreduce](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/labs.google.com/en//papers/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) ([hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is the framework implementation in java)

your `map` stage will parse each line and extract relevant key and value for each line.

 your `reduce` stage will summarize all the data for the given key.

Comment: In fact, I tried to use this approach, I just didn't know that it is called map/reduce. Problem is, that the dataset is quite huge even _after_ the final reduction (before any 'get only top 5' applies). I can divide it into smaller groups, and select 'top5' from them, but this could return wrong data.

Comment: (there may be even 10^9 rows which has unique keys - I'm not able to detect this)

Comment: the map/reduce framework should take care of it for you (if you are using an existing library). besides, as long as your data is smaller then 2^system_bits, even if the data does not fit in RAM, the OS will take care of it by swapping data to disk, so practically, 64bits system will not face this problem.